# How to make alignment on console in php

Tags: php, command-line, console, alignment

I am trying to run a script through command prompt in PHP and trying to show the result in tabular form. But due to different character length of words I am not able to show the result properly align.

I want result like this

```
Book                  ISBN      Department
Operating System      101       CS
C                     102       CS
java                  103       CS
```

Can anyone please help me to get this output like this in php on console.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you don't want (or not allowed for some reason) to use libraries, you can use standard php [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) / [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) functions.

The problem with them that if you have values with variable and non-limited width, then you will have to decide if long values will be truncated or break table's layout.

First case:

```
// fixed width
$mask = "|%5.5s |%-30.30s | x |\n";
printf($mask, 'Num', 'Title');
printf($mask, '1', 'A value that fits the cell');
printf($mask, '2', 'A too long value the end of which will be cut off');
```

The output is

```
|  Num |Title                          | x |
|    1 |A value that fits the cell     | x |
|    2 |A too long value the end of wh | x |
```

Second case:

```
// only min-width of cells is set
$mask = "|%5s |%-30s | x |\n";
printf($mask, 'Num', 'Title');
printf($mask, '1', 'A value that fits the cell');
printf($mask, '2', 'A too long value that will brake the table');
```

And here we get

```
|  Num |Title                          | x |
|    1 |A value that fits the cell     | x |
|    2 |A too long value that will brake the table | x |
```

If neither of that satisfies your needs and you really need a table with flowing width columns, than you have to calculate maximum width of values in each column. But that is how `PEAR::Console_Table` exactly works.

Comment: Why? Too long values brake the table? Then you first need to find the longest string in each column. That really looks like reinventing a wheel, because the PEAR solution suggested by powtac does that for you. So I give up on my answer and support his.

Comment: +1 - If you don't want to opt for a library (yet), `sprintf` is a good start for formatted output, check the different formats available: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php - you can use the same mask for your table's header row as well as the data rows.

Answer (score 35):

You can use [PEAR::Console_Table](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-table.examples.php):

> [Console_Table](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-table.introduction.php) helps you to display tabular data on a
>   terminal/shell/console.

**Example:**

```
require_once 'Console/Table.php';

$tbl = new Console_Table();

$tbl->setHeaders(array('Language', 'Year'));

$tbl->addRow(array('PHP', 1994));
$tbl->addRow(array('C',   1970));
$tbl->addRow(array('C++', 1983));

echo $tbl->getTable();
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+------+
| Language | Year |
+----------+------+
| PHP      | 1994 |
| C        | 1970 |
| C++      | 1983 |
+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 9):

Your best option is to use the Pear Package Console_Table ( http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table/ ).

To use - on a console you need to install the pear package, running:

```
pear install Console_Table
```

this should download the package and install. You can then use a sample script such as:

```
require_once 'Console/Table.php';

$tbl = new Console_Table();
$tbl->setHeaders(
    array('Language', 'Year')
);
$tbl->addRow(array('PHP', 1994));
$tbl->addRow(array('C',   1970));
$tbl->addRow(array('C++', 1983));

echo $tbl->getTable();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try the recent simple PHP library [ConsoleTable](https://github.com/phplucidframe/console-table) if you don't want to use the standard PHP functions [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)/[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or the pear package [PEAR::Console_Table](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-table.examples.php).

**Example:**

```
require_once 'ConsoleTable.php';

$table = new LucidFrame\Console\ConsoleTable();
$table
    ->addHeader('Language')
    ->addHeader('Year')
    ->addRow()
        ->addColumn('PHP')
        ->addColumn(1994)
    ->addRow()
        ->addColumn('C++')
        ->addColumn(1983)
    ->addRow()
        ->addColumn('C')
        ->addColumn(1970)
    ->display()
;
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+------+
| Language | Year |
+----------+------+
| PHP      | 1994 |
| C++      | 1983 |
| C        | 1970 |
+----------+------+
```

See more example usages at [its github page](https://github.com/phplucidframe/console-table).

Answer (score 3):

Too old, but i went trough the same now and used str_pad, just set the lenght as the size of your column and thats it

regards.

Comment: Unlike the other answers, with str_pad is possible to echo content before you have all line content, so this is a better option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The CLIFramework table generator helps you get the job done very easily and it supports text alignment, text color, background color, text wrapping, text overflow handling.. etc

Here is the tutorial: https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework/wiki/Using-Table-Component

Sample code: https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework/blob/master/example/table.php

```
use CLIFramework\Component\Table\Table;

$table = new Table;
$table->setHeaders([ 'Published Date', 'Title', 'Description' ]);
$table->addRow(array( 
    "September 16, 2014",
    "Title",
    "Description",
    29.5
));
$table->addRow(array( 
    "November 4, 2014",
    "Hooked: How to Build Habit-Forming Products",
    ["Why do some products capture widespread attention whil..."],
    99,
));
echo $table->render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone wants to do that in PHP I posted a gist on Github

https://gist.github.com/redestructa/2a7691e7f3ae69ec5161220c99e2d1b3

simply call:

```
$output = $tablePrinter->printLinesIntoArray($items, ['title', 'chilProp2']);
```

you may need to adapt the code if you are using a php version older than 7.2

after that call echo or writeLine depending on your environment.