# Convert HTML table to text

Tags: php, html, text, html-table

I'm working on a project that requires to convert html email into text. Below is a simplified version of the HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"></td>
        <td width="60%"> test product </td>
        <td width="20%">5</td>
        <td width="10%"> £50.00 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3" width="100%"> Project Name: Test Project </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="80%"> Page 1 : 01 New York 1.jpg </td>
        <td width="10%"> £0.00 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The expected outcome should look like this in a text file (with columns aligned nicely):

```
test product                                      5            £50.00
Project Name: Test Project                                                            
Page 1 :  01 New York 1.jpg                                    £0.00
```

My idea is parsing the HTML content by DOMDocument. Then I will set a default width for the table (i.e.: 100 spaces) then convert the width of each column from % to number of spaces (based on `colspan` & `width` attribute of `<td>` tag). Then I will subtract these column width to `strlen` of the data in each column to archive the number of spaces I need to pad_right to the string to make everything align vertically.

I have been working that way, hasn't been archived what I want but just wondering if it is stupid or anyone knows a better way please help me out.

Also when it comes to Multibyte languages (Japanese, Korean etc...) I don't think my approach would work because their characters will be bigger than one space and it end up a mess.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: This could only work if the text is displayed in a monospace font.

Comment: Huh? Multibyte doesn't (/ shouldn't) take more spaces in your txtfile.

Comment: What will you do if there's a column which is wider than what you're expecting?

Comment: @roman: yes i think so too but haven't figured out a better solution.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I think it does, ie: this "語" definatelly looks bigger than "s" :)

Comment: @Truth: good point, if the text inside column is longer than the number of spaces allocated then i will need to break it into 2 lines (just add an "\r" i assume).

Comment: @Olizt: It's not that simple, the line-break will break the entire line, not just the column. Remember that it is not a real table!

Comment: @Truth: yeah you're absolutely right. I'm stump.

Comment: @Olizt lol. Right you were talking about that6, which shouldn't be an issue because you need to use a non-proportional font anyway for a decent result.

Comment: Simply set border width as '0'

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039010/how-to-make-alignment-on-console-in-php). For a more complete solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Table rendering is difficult, rendering tables using only text is even more difficult.
To clarify the complexity of a text-based table renderer that offers all the features of HTML, take a look at w3m, which is open source:
[these 3000 lines of code](https://github.com/tats/w3m/blob/master/table.c) are there only to display html tables.

## Transform HTML to Text

There are textbased browsers that can be used by command line, like lynx. 
You could `fwrite` your html table into a file, pass that file into the textbased browser and take its output.

Note: textbased browsers are generally used in a shell, which generally displays in monospace. This remains a prerequisite.

lynx and w3m are both available on Windows and you don't need to "install" them, you just need to have the executables and the permission to run them from PHP.

code example:

```
<?php
$table = '<table><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>'; //this contains your table
$html = "<html><body>$table</body></html>";

//write html file
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "tblemail");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $html);
fclose($handle);

$myTextTable = shell_exec("w3m.exe -dump \"$tmpfname\"");
unlink($tmpfname);
```

`w3m.exe` needs to be in your working directory.

(didn't try it)

## Render a Text table

If you want a native PHP solution, there's also at least one framework (https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework) aimed at console applications for PHP which has a table renderer.

It doesn't transform HTML to text, but it helps you build a text formatted table with support for multiline cells (which seems to be the most complicated part).

Using CLIFramework you would need a code like this to render your table:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use CLIFramework\Component\Table\Table;

$table = new Table;
$table->addRow(array( 
    "test product", "5", "£50.00"
));
$table->addRow(array( 
    "Project Name: Test Project", "", ""
));
$table->addRow(array( 
    "Page 1 : 01 New York 1.jpg", "", "£0.00"
));

$myTextTable = $table->render();
```

The CLIFramework table renderer doesn't seem to support anything similar to "colspan" however.

Here's the documentation for the table component: https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework/wiki/Using-Table-Component

Comment: Thanks, the problem is this conversion must be automatic & is a part of our company software which is run on a Window server so i can't really install Lynx

Comment: Oh, I thought it to be automatic. The idea was to automate it. PHP writes the file and executes (shell_exec) the browser. I'll add a code exmaple

Comment: @Olizt see above: "lynx and w3m are both available on Windows"!

Comment: @feeela I added the part about windows in an update, after he said it needs to be run on windows ;)

Comment: Thanks Roman, i'll give it a try and let you know if it works. :)

Comment: Great idea. I tested both, but settled on Lynx because it applied text alignment better. It's worth noting if the output is intended to be used in an email, that line ending conversion is needed depending on the environment. Mine is Linux, which produced "\n" line endings, but plain text email requires "\r\n" line endings.