# Beautifying data & records for showing in client output

Tags: php, html, command-line-interface

i need a plugin/component/code or anything else that beautifying my data

in my framework terminal (countdown) user can see my commands list with this command:

> php countdown help

i wanna show the commands in some style like this:

[image: CountDown commands list]

since the countdown commands are specific and are not changeable, i can create this format in some txt file and when user type the help command print it by getting its content in terminal

but in some cases, such as when user wanna see the routes, i need to put the unknown datas in this text. so i need an function for example that i can put my user routes in its arguments with an array for example and it create this format text for me

something like this:

```
$headers = array('Command', 'Description', 'Arguments');
$help_command = Text_Beautifer(self::$commands, $headers);

$headers = array('Route', 'Path', 'Middleware');
$routes = Text_Beautifer(self::$routes, $headers);
```

anyone has idea about it ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two questions implied here:

- how to beautify console output?
- how to manage information related to commands?

### how to beautify console output

The easiest way to get started is to use the `printf` command to format the output for your listing.

There are many examples here in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

And there is a nice answer here on [How to make alignment on console in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039063/8968340).

Perhaps the trickiest aspect of printing a table in the terminal is adjusting the output to the width of the terminal and analyzing your data to know how wide to make your columns before you start to print.

Here is a simple table with some ideas to get started:

```php
$width=22;
echo str_repeat("-", $width)."\n";
printf( "| %-10s",  "name");
printf( "| %6d", 44);
echo " |\n";
echo str_repeat("-", $width)."\n";
```

creates this:

```sh
----------------------
| name      |     44 |
----------------------
```

you can retrieve the width of the terminal window with:

```php
$width=intval(shell_exec("tput cols");
```

the rest of the calculations are up to you.

---

### how to manage information related to commands

As my suite of scripts and commands for the command line have grown, I have started to consider a framework for organizing the logic and presentation.

[Symfony Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) is looking pretty good. It handles the management of command options and their requirements, as well as help text.